# HTTP cache not expires with Slim Framework

Tags: php, http, caching, frameworks, slim

I'm using Slim framework in order to develop an API.

I wanted to cache some request in the HTTP cache with:

```
$app->etag('Unique-ID')
```

But the time expiration didn't seems to work :

```
$app->expires('10 seconds')
```

When i look the headers with Chrome, first call i get a 200 Status Code : OK.

Second call, i get a 304 Status Code : OK.

Waiting 30 seconds.

Third call, i still get a 304 Status Code : NOT OK in my mind.

Should i not get a 200 Status Code because the cache is expired ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to use +10 seconds?

Comment: @François Lefebvre have you got your exact answer for expire() or you are using below answer ? if you got answer with expire() then please tell me also, i am also facing that problem

Comment: Hi, from memory I used the response of Mika Tuupola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In short

`Expires` header instructs the browser how long it should cache content in client side cache. Browser will serve the content from client side cache until the expiration date is reached.

When client side cache is expired browser will send request to server again. Request includes `If-None-Match` header with the previous `Etag` value it received from server. If value of `If-None-Match` header still matches current `Etag` value on server it will respond with `304 Not Modified`.

When you use `Etag` and `If-None-Match` headers and want server to send updated content, value of `Etag` header must change.

## Longer explanation

Lest assume you have the following code.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get("/hello", function() use ($app){
    $app->etag("unique-etag-1");
    echo "Hello world.\n";
});

$app->run();
```

Then you make a request.

```
$ curl --include http://localhost:8080/hello

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Etag: "unique-etag-1"

Hello world
```

On subsequent requests browser will send `If-None-Match` request header. Value of this header is the same as value of previously received `Etag` header.

When Slim receives the request it compares the value of `If-None-Match` header to the value you set with `$app->etag()` call. If these match `304 Not Modified` will be returned.

```
$ curl --include --header 'If-None-Match: "unique-etag-1"' http://localhost:8080/hello

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Etag: "unique-etag-1"
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If the content of URI changes or you want to browser to refetch the content for some other reasons, change the value of `Etag` header.

```
$app->get("/hello", function() use ($app){
    $app->etag("unique-etag-2");
    echo "Hello world.\n";
});
```

Now when browser makes new request you will get `200 OK` response.

```
curl --include --header 'If-None-Match: "unique-etag-1"' http://localhost:8080/hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Etag: "unique-etag-2"

Hello world.
```

Comment: But in this way you should change Etag(and no need to set `expires`), and OP was talking about expires time. So, after this time etag will not be valid and slim will not sent 304(that's why he set 10 seconds)

Comment: He was asking why Slim still responds 304 after content has expired. Etag is the reason. Expires just instructs browser to cache content locally for n seconds. When content is cached locally request will not even be sent to server (unless forced with reload). After local cache expires browser sends request to server again. If etag still matches 304 is returned.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I understood his question in wrong way